Python regular expression for multiple split criteria
I'm struggling to split some text in a piece of code that I'm writing. This software is scanning through about 3.5 million lines of text of which there are varying formats throughout.
I'm kind of working my way through everything still, but the line below appears to be fairly standard within the file:
EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT ID="20211111.111111 11111"

I want to split it as follows:
EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT, ID, 20211111.111111 11111

As much as possible, I'd prefer to avoid hard coding any certain text to look for as I'm still parsing through the file & trying to determine all the different variables. I've tried running the following code:
conditioned_line = re.sub(r'(\w+=)(\w+)', r'\1"\2"', input_line)
output = shlex.split(conditioned_line)

When I run this code, I'm getting this output:
['EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT', 'ID=20211111.111111 11111']

I've managed to successfully split each and every element of this, but I have not managed to split them all together successfully. I suspect this is manageable via a regular expression, or with a regular expression and a shlex split, but I could really use some suggestions if anyone has some ideas.
As requested, here's another example of some text that's in the file I'm scanning:
EXAMPLE_TEXT TAG="AB-123-ABCD_$B" ABCDE_ABCD="ABCD_A" ABCDEF_ABCDE="ABCDEF_ABCDEF_$A" ABCDEFGH=""

This should separate to the following:
EXAMPLE_TEXT, TAG, AB-123-ABCD_$B, ABCDE_ABCD, ABCD_A, ABCDEF_ABCDE, ABCDEF_ABCDEF_$A, ABCDEFGH


Maybe something like this can help.

@WiktorStribiżew solution works perfect for your scenario rather than mine, pls check this once

@WiktorStribiżew - Thank you for the help! This does seem to work for the scenario initially listed in my example as well as subsequent ones. There's some extra blank items in my list but I believe I can filter those out by pre-conditioning the text a bit before it reaches the re statement.

I suggest a tokenizing approach with regex: create a regex with alternations, starting with the most specific ones, and ending with somewhat generic ones.
In your case, you may try
import re
x = 'EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT ID="20211111.111111 11111"'
res = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"|(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)|(\w+)', x)
print( ["".join(r) for r in res] )
# => ['EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT', 'ID', '20211111.111111 11111']

See the Python demo.
The regex matches

"([^"]*)" - a string between two double quotes: " matches a ", then ([^"]*) captures zero or more chars other than " and then " matches a " char (NOTE: to match string between quotes with escaped quote support use "([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)", add a similar pattern for single quotes if needed)
| - or
(\d+(?:\.\d+)*) - Group 2: one or more digits and then zero or more sequences of . and one or more digits
| - or
(\w+) - Group 3: one or more word chars.


Thank you. This solution works perfectly. I'm very inexperienced in the realm of regex so I will need to do some studying up on tokenization / alternations, but from a conceptual perspective, this makes sense. It answers all of the above as well as gives me something else to dig into & learn more about as I parse through the rest of this text. Thanks again, I've marked this as the accepted answer :)

What you can try is
import re

text = 'EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT ID="20211111.111111 11111"'
pattern = r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)="([^"]*)"'
matches = re.findall(pattern, text)

if matches:
    result = list(matches[0])  
    print(result)

which results
=================== RESTART: C:\Users\Bhargav\Desktop\test.py ==================
['EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT', 'ID', '20211111.111111 11111']

Explination
(\w+) - EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT
\s+ - Matches whitespace
(\w+) - ID
=" - Matches equals and opening quote
([^"]*) - Captures everything inside the quotes
" - Matches the closing quote

If you looking like as you mentioned in your question then
print(','.join(result))

Results
EXAMPLE_FILE_TEXT,ID,20211111.111111 11111


If you only want the first match, use re.search() rather than re.findall().

This works great. I suppose that I can define multiple patterns using re.findall and handle different cases this way, right?
I've found that I have some other examples for instance that this removes some of the data I need to keep.

Its hard to assume and test hypothetical scenarios that you talking about. pls provide the cases where you getting cropped results so that we can modify the case accordingly

As requested, I added a cropped response in the original text. In this case, I'm only seeing the first 3 items in my output with the current re.findall.

@Wiktor Stribiżew solution works perfect for your scenario

Seems I overlooked this comment. You are correct, this works perfectly for both of these scenarios. Thanks for the help!
